# ¿Alguno sabe cuál es el origen de la interjección "qué rayos"? ¿Y un sinónimo?

Tags: interjecciones

Quisiera saber el origen de la interjección "qué rayos". Por ejemplo, "¿Qué rayos es eso?".  Y si conocen algún sinónimo.

Comment: As far as synonyms go you might be interested in https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/7007/what-the-hell-in-spanish/18942#18942

Answer (score 1):

Esto es solo mi opinión, desconozco cómo ha sido explicado por los gramáticos.

"Rayos" es una interjección que expresa sorpresa y un poco de desagrado, tal vez alerta. No hay mucho que explicar sobre su origen, los rayos son sorpresivos y desagradables (al menos en la época en que se empezó a usar esa palabra como interjección).

Cuando la intercalas en una interrogación, haces que la pregunta se "cargue" afectivamente, de modo que deja de ser solo una solicitud de datos y pasa a informar explícitamente tu opinión sobre el objeto de la pregunta o sobre tu estado de ánimo al preguntar.

> ¿Qué es eso? (Estoy diciendo que no sé qué es).
>
> ¿Qué *rayos* es eso? (Estoy diciendo que no sé qué es y que me causa sorpresa).

Sinónimos hay varios relativos al diablo:

> ¿Qué diablos...? ¿Qué demonios...? ¿Que diantres...?

Y todos los informales, obscenos, locales y feos que se nos ocurran

> ¿Qué cresta...? ¿Qué coño...? ¿Qué mierda...? ¿Qué chucha...?

Answer (score 0):

El origen de la interjección "¡rayos!" se encuentra en la idea y concepto de castigo que en la antigüedad se tenía de este elemento.

En la antigüedad los rayos eran considerados males o castigos enviados por Dios, según la antigua tradición Zeus fabricaba los truenos y los rayos al batir su égida (la égida era un elemento principal en la armadura de Zeus a modo de cobertor con piel de cabra, escudo o coraza que lo protegía) en el aire. Las personas tenían gran terror  a ser alcanzadas por un rayo, por la muerte que podía llegar o sus graves quemaduras y consecuencias.

[image]

Así cuando alguien había hecho un gran daño general a otro, pensaban que sería castigado por un rayo fulgurante por la maldad cometida, frases como "así le caiga un rayo", "que le caiga un rayo", "te parta un rayo", "mal rayo te parta"... eran típicas para referirse a ese tipo de castigo máximo que Dios debía mandar a una persona que había perjudicado a otro o comportado de forma poco apropiada.

De esta manera el castigo del rayo, paso a ser cualquier otra contrariedad o evento calamitoso que pudiera ocurrirles a las personas, viendo en ello una forma alternativa de aquel otro castigo divino enviado o encarnado por Dios o por un espíritu maléfico, de la memoria popular, que trataba de frenar cualquier actividad del ser humano, enunciando así la palabra "rayos" para referirse de forma espontánea a cualquier mal, infortunio, problema, inconveniente, asombro o sorpresa, en el que el individuo se queda por un instante pasmado.

Con el tiempo otras calamidades y aparentes contratiempos que aparecían de manera fortuita o sorpresiva se fueron añadiendo y manifestando en el mismo tono de interjección con palabras que expresaban parecidas o relacionadas analogías, dios, demonios, diablos, centellas, truenos, maldición...y que a veces unidas, podían ocupar el mismo espacio y dar un sentido de profundidad al propio malestar dentro de la misma expresión, "truenos y centellas", "rayos y relámpagos", "rayos y demonios", "rayos y culebras"...  para llegar a otras que poco tenían que ver con las anteriores, como diantres, carajo, caracoles... y añadiendo palabras correlativas en su discurrir como, qué demonios, qué diablos, qué carajo, por los clavos de Cristo, por las espinas de Cristo...